# Vertical page setting using memoir

Tags: header-footer, memoir

I'm trying to adjust the `A5` layout shipped with `memoir`. To that end consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[9pt,a5paper,extrafontsizes,twoside]{memoir}
\fixpdflayout
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

which yields:

[image]

My goal is to decrease the upper and lower margins. First, in order to have a

```
high\settypeblocksize{*}{\lxvchars}{1.618}
```

to the preamble. This yields:

[image]

So far so good... Now I try to translate the block upwards, and this is where I fail. As far as I can understand the manual I have to add something like `\setulmargins{30pt}{*}{*}`. But this seems to have no (visual) effect (regardless of the value I use).

I guess this is a simple one, but I just couldn't manage to solve it. **How can I reduce the whitespace at the top of the page?**

Comment: did you consider using package geometry??

Comment: @Umz: I got the impression that this is discouraged with `memoir`, and things should be handled directly from the class.

Comment: See if this works: if u add  \checkandfixthelayout  after \setulmargins{30pt}{*}{*}.

Comment: I got one paragraph behind the relevant part in the manual. Thanks. PLease turn this into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
\documentclass[9pt,a5paper,extrafontsizes,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setulmargins{30pt}{*}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

For further reference, see section 2.6 in the manual (v. 3.7b)